# "Outlook blocked access to the following potentially unsafe attachments"

Tags: outlook, outlook-2010, office-2010

Recently, we have some users which suddenly got this massege:
"Outlook blocked access to the following potentially unsafe attachments"
(outlook 2010 plus)

I had tried all of this: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/829982/outlook-blocked-access-to-the-following-potentially-unsafe-attachment
but nothing had changed...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We recently had the same issue, when I removed KB3203467 (Security Update for Microsoft Outlook 2010) - this resolved the issue immediately.

Comment: I had an issue with the KB4022715 update which breaks Outlook search, and removed it from two pc's. Both wouldn't boot after. Is there a risk of this happening with KB3203467?

Comment: In reaction to the previous comment - there is a fix available, see issue #5 mentioned here: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Outlook-known-issues-in-the-June-2017-security-updates-3f6dbffd-8505-492d-b19f-b3b89369ed9b

Answer (score 5):

I was able to permanently unblock files with specific extensions by applying the following procedure, that I found [at sitepoint.com](https://www.sitepoint.com/outlook-unblock-unsafe-attachments/) :

1. Close Outlook
2. Run your Registry Editor (`regedit.exe`)
3. Go to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER/SOFTWARE/Microsoft/Office/XX/Outlook/Security`, where `XX` corresponds with your version of Office
4. Create a new key of the type `String Value`, named `Level1Remove`
5. Add the extensions you want to unblock, separated by `;` characters 
   (for example : `.js;.vbs;.exe`)
6. Restart Outlook

If that doesn't work, the issue is probably caused by one of Microsoft's June 2017 security patches. Instead of removing the security patch responsible, you might want to consider [one of the fixes or workarounds mentioned here](https://www.howto-outlook.com/news/attachments-blocked-after-applying-june-2017-updates.htm).

Comment: Is there a way to do something similar on a Mac?

Answer (score 4):

The update blocks access to attachments with long filenames and/or file names with consecutive periods

Remove this update to fix :-
(might want to decline these updates in WSUS to prevent re-installation)

Outlook 2007: KB3191898
Outlook 2010: KB3203467
Outlook 2013: KB3191938
Outlook 2016: KB3191932

Replaced with :-

Outlook 2010  KB4011042
Outlook 2013  KB3191849
Outlook 2016  Fixed in build 1706 - run Office update (note not fixed in Deferred channel)
No fix for Outlook 2007

Answer (score 1):

if this message comes "Outlook blocked access to the following potentially unsafe attachments" message in Outlook"

Outlook goto Junk option , Never block Option

click it

then file will accessible.

Answer (score 1):

We have Outlook 1808 (Office 365 up-to-date as of March 2019) and we were still receiving this message with a pdf.

We just added the sender to the Safe Senders list and restarted Outlook:

- Home -> Junk -> Junk E-mail Options -> Safe Senders -> Add the email address (this really should be a button)
- Tick the 'Automatically add people I email to the Safe Senders List'